# Android GameHelper Leaderboards closed listener/detector

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a way to detect whether Leaderboards was closed?

When "highscores" is clicked there is a short amount of time when the leaderboards load where you can still click on the main UI. Is there a way to stop any further input to the main UI when "highscores" is clicked?

My current plan is: once "highscores" is clicked, set InputProcessor to null, then bring InputProcessor back to normal once Leaderboards is closed. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How do you launch the leaderboards activity? I cannot reproduce such problem. Even when the activity is starting slow, with 1-2 seconds delay before showing on the screen, I cannot touch anything inside the game.

Comment: like this http://imgur.com/a/aqQBn here's a convo regarding the issue https://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/55ydxu/android_gamehelper_leaderboards_closed/

Comment: how do you launch your leaderboards activity?

Comment: I think libgdx may call your click listener more than once, so maybe you're seeing this. I would do it like you said in the answer - setInputProcessor(null) and later restore it if that bothers you. I don't have this problem, because I don't have any logic when a leaderboards or achievements button is clicked. The only thing I do in these cases is: startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), 42); and even if libgdx makes 2-3 click events, the Android system does not open 2-3 leaderboards. So basically, I ignore this issue, although it exists :)

Comment: how do u implement your InputListener/ClickListener? do you do it like: Actor.addListener(new ClickListener(){ });

Comment: here's the game if you're interested in seeing the bug in action: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsa.game

Comment: Hi, I tried the game, but couldn't reproduce the issue. How should I click?

Comment: That's very good to hear! try spam clicking the highscores i.e. just keep pressing on it quickly as the highscores load

Answer (score -1):

Call the leaderboard with the `activitiy.startActivityForResult()` method. The second parameter is a request code, which you may choose.

In your `activity` you override the method `onActivityResult()` where you have to catch the chosen request code. The result code should be 0 or `RESULT_CANCELED`, when the leaderboard was closed.